# Docker/Jupyter notebook setting Base URL

Tags: ubuntu, docker, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Using this [docker image](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/all-spark-notebook) which includes Jupyter and Spark, among other nice tools I get it to start up fine but it is in it's own world. I want to access the files on my local machine.

The instructions indicate to start it with the following to set a custom Base url

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/all-spark-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.base_url=/some/path
```

However I cannot figure out a valid path syntax

I have tried /Home, ~/Home, /home, ~/home as well as longer versions. I keep getting the Jupyter notebook page saying 404??

Any Ideas?

Using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to access the files on your local machine, you'll need to mount a volume to the docker container. Your command for start-notebook.sh will have to reference a path that is relevant to your docker container, which would be the right-side of the volume argument:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v /some/path/on/my/local:/some/path/on/my/container jupyter/all-spark-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.base_url=/some/path/on/my/container
```

Comment: In the current case I am running Docker on my local machine.. I tried both of the following with no luck... I can't even write to whatever got done (permission denied?)  docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v ~/tom/Documents/:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/all-spark-notebook
^^ ng tried
tom@tom-sam:~$ docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v /Documents/:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/all-spark-notebook

Comment: Finally got it! in case someone else follows:
tom@tom-sam:~$ docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v ~/Documents/:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/all-spark-notebook